# Suhosin - Disable shell_exec default, allow from one directory

Tags: php, vps, shell, apache-2.4

I have in php ini this function, which blocks shell_exec default.
php.ini

> suhosin.executor.func.blacklist = shell_exec

Its works well.
When I want to allow shell_exec, so I use in httpd.conf this function in directory, which allow function.
This function is

> < Directory "/crons" >
>
> ```
> php_admin_value suhosin.executor.func.blacklist  “shell_exec”
> ```
>
> < /Directory >

This allow function for one dir. Its work well. If write adress to webbrowser, its ok. Function for this dir is allowed.

But if in shell write:

> php /crons/e.php

So I get in console php error shell_exec it is disabled.
Because it works in web browser, but not working for bash?

Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP on the command line does not use Apache php_admin_value. You can use

```
php -d "suhosin.executor.func.blacklist=" e.php
```

Or use a custom php.ini file:

```
php -n -c php.ini e.php
```

Or configure php-cli with a custom php.ini file (check `php --ini`) - usually something like /etc/php5/cli/php.ini.